# Assignment of AWS Elastic API makes the site unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have an EC2 instance running with an Elastic API. As the instance is years old, I have set up a new instance with the latest AMI and other packages, which was working well on testing.

In order to make the new instance live, I tried assigning the Elastic IP from the previous instance to the new one but as I assigned the site went down. I had tried this several time but every time the site does down.

Can anyone share thoughts on this and any possible root cause of why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your new EC2 instance has the same inbound rules like the old one?

Comment: One possible reason is mentioned by @Juned, double-check the security group of the newly created instance. also, make sure the IP assigned properly and do `curl` of `private IP` address of the instance to verify the application is running or not or release the Elastic IP and verify the accessiblity if not accessible it mean something wrong with instance

Comment: If you think it because of Elastic IP, try to access the instance with private IP with in VPC.

Comment: Instance is available on private IP

Comment: okay so one thing clear, that instance is available on private IP, is your new instance in private subnet or public subnet? if its in private subnet it should available over elastic IP

Answer (score 0):

Assigning elastic IP is not going to affect your server.

There is either something wrong with the application running on your EC2 instance

or

something else in your inbound path that is not allowing the traffic to reach your new EC2 instance. Most likely the security group configuration or any other firewall installed on your instance.

Comment: I did check all these and all traffic is already allowed. As I mentioned, the instance was working well during testing. The only change I am doing with the instance is that I am assigned an elastic IP to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by cloning the existing instance, doing required changes, launching. Assigning IP to that cloned instance worked well.

What I understood is that, there must be a configuration done in the instance itself which as blocking the requests to reach the desired server.

I will debug the instance further to find the actual root cause but for now the problem has been resolved.